# exchange globale variable between worker thread epolled and a config thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, mutex, epoll

I have a worker thread that do epoll_wait on fds and timer with a config stored in a global context structure(fdToRead).
Some other threads change this global structure.

This is the schematic principe

worker thread

```
struct epoll_event ev
while(1){
    epoll_wait(&ev)
    // call to changeFd(path) done here from other thread
    get_mutex
    read(ev.data.fd)//this fd was just closed or re-affect to another file !!!
    ...
    put_mutex
}
```

function call from any thread

```
changeFd(path){
  get_mutex
  close(fdToRead)
  fdToRead=openSocket(path)
  epoll_add(fdToRead)
  put_mutex
}
```

The problem is if changeFd is call after epoll_wait and before get_mutex, i receive event on a fd that is closed or re-affect to another "open file desciptor in kernel".

In Which way can i do that?
Which that template patern?

Is it possible to do something like "get_mutex inside the epoll_wait" ?
Or, "can i block " worker thread in the epoll_wait call?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [accept()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/accept) function, it permit to you to accept a new connection on a socket, you code may look like following:

```
mutex_lock(...)
epoll_wait(...);
accept(...);
mutex_unlock(...);
```

Comment: sorry, this doesn't slove  my problem, i know how use mutex. The problem is the use of epoll and mutex simultaenous

Comment: don't work, epoll_wait can wait for a long time, and so the config will wait for the mutex a long time